# Selenium : Scraping depending on the number of pages for each category of a website

Tags: python, selenium

I did web scraping in this website: http://www.legorafi.fr/
It works with each categories (politique, etc) but for each category I loop through the same number of pages.

I would like to be able to scrape all the pages depending on the numbers of pages for each category in this website.

I did this to loop through pages:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

import newspaper
import requests
from newspaper.utils import BeautifulSoup
from newspaper import Article

#categories = ['france/politique','france/societe', 'monde-libre', 'france/economie/', 'culture', 'people', 'sports', 'hi-tech', 'sciences']
papers = []


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/name/Downloads/chromedriver 4")
#driver.get('http://www.legorafi.fr/')


for category in categories:
    url = 'http://www.legorafi.fr/category/' + category
    #WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
    driver.get(url)
    Foo()
    
    time.sleep(2)
    pagesToGet = 120

pagesToGet = 120

title = []
content = []
for page in range(1, pagesToGet+1):
    print('Processing page :', page)
    #url = 'http://www.legorafi.fr/category/france/politique/page/'+str(page)
    print(driver.current_url)
    #print(url)
    
    raw_html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html.text, 'html.parser')
    for articles_tags in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'articles'}):
        for article_href in articles_tags.find_all('a', href=True):
            if not str(article_href['href']).endswith('#commentaires'):
                urls_set.add(article_href['href'])
                papers.append(article_href['href'])

                
    for url in papers:
        article = Article(url)
        article.download()
        article.parse()
        if article.title not in title:
            title.append(article.title)
        if article.text not in content:
            content.append(article.text)
        print(article.title,article.text)

    time.sleep(3)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Suivant')]").click()
```

I would like to loop through all these categories and depending on the number of pages for each categories.

```
categories = ['france/politique','france/societe', 'monde-libre', 'france/economie/', 'culture', 'people', 'sports', 'hi-tech', 'sciences']
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below was able to traverse all the categories and extract data.  The code definitely needs more testing and some enhanced error handling.

P.S. good luck in this coding project.

```
import requests

import time
from random import randint
from datetime import datetime

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

from newspaper.utils import BeautifulSoup
from newspaper import Article

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--test-type")
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

# window size as an argument is required in headless mode
# chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

papers = []
urls_set = set()


def get_articles(link):
   while True:
      try:
        next_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Suivant")
        if next_link:
            raw_html = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html.text, 'html.parser')
            for articles_tags in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'articles'}):
                for article_href in articles_tags.find_all('a', href=True):
                    if not str(article_href['href']).endswith('#commentaires'):
                        article = Article(article_href['href'])
                        article.download()
                        article.parse()
                        if article.url is not None:
                            article_url = article_href['href']
                            title = article.title
                            publish_date = datetime.strptime(str(article.publish_date),
                                                             '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                            
                            text_of_article = article.text.replace('\n', '')

            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", next_link)
            next_link.click()

            # Initiates a random wait to prevent the
            # harvesting operation from starting before
            # the page has completely loaded
            time.sleep(randint(2, 4))

    except NoSuchElementException:
        return



 legorafi_urls = {'monde-libre': 'http://www.legorafi.fr/category/monde-libre',
             'politique': 'http://www.legorafi.fr/category/france/politique',
             'societe': 'http://www.legorafi.fr/category/france/societe',
             'economie': 'http://www.legorafi.fr/category/france/economie',
             'culture': 'http://www.legorafi.fr/category/culture',
             'people': 'http://www.legorafi.fr/category/people',
             'sports': 'http://www.legorafi.fr/category/sports',
             'hi-tech': 'http://www.legorafi.fr/category/hi-tech',
             'sciences': 'http://www.legorafi.fr/category/sciences',
             'ledito': 'http://www.legorafi.fr/category/ledito/'
             }


for category, url in legorafi_urls.items():
   if url:
     browser = driver.get(url)
     driver.implicitly_wait(30)
     get_articles(browser)
  else:
     driver.quit()
```

Comment: @LJRB You're welcome.  It's was an interesting issue to work on.